# Passing values to php from my android application

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm passing values selected from my android application to a server via php using this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['states']) && isset($_POST['min_budget']) && $_POST['max_budget'] && $_POST['activity']){  

// check for post data
$states = $_POST['states'];
$min_budget = $_POST['min_budget'];
$max_budget = $_POST['max_budget'];
$activity = $_POST['activity'];


        // get resorts from resort table


$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT resorts.resort_name , room_prices.2A FROM resorts inner join room_prices on room_prices.resort_id =resorts.id inner join resort_activities on resorts.id = resort_activities.resort_id inner join activities on resort_activities.id = activities.id WHERE resorts.state_id = (SELECT id FROM states WHERE name = $sname) and activities.activity_name = $activity and room_prices.2A between $min_budget and $max_budget order by room_prices.2A");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $response["resorts"] = array();
    $response["room_prices"] = array();

    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $response["resorts"][$i] = $row["resort_name"];
        $response["room_prices"][$i] = $row["2A"];
        $i++;
    }


    $response["success"] = 1;


} else {
    // no resort found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No resort found";

}
```

But every time I get `{"success":0,"message":"No resort found"}` in my logcat in Android. What am I doing wrong?

My java code:

```
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("states", states));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("min_budget", min_budget));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("max_budget", max_budget));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("activity", activity));


        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        try {
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_resorts, "POST", params);
            Log.d("All Resorts : ", json.toString());
```

jParser is an object of type JSONparser class

```
        public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

            try{
            if(method.equals("POST")){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: first your method is GET or POST ?

Comment: You post value, bue access with get.

Comment: Apologies I accidentally entered GET. It is POST @JYoThI

Comment: What is your SQL query? You must include php variables into the query. Looks like $min_budget and $max_budget are not included in query.

Comment: if you want to fetching the data twice form result set  means you need to use mysql_data_seek($result, 0); before second while loop to reset the internal data pointer to 0 . otherwise you will get error .

Comment: why your revert the same GET method @DhruvVerma

Comment: I did that @vishalk still the same result.

Comment: I put it in the same loop @JYoThI

Comment: first echo the query run it directly in database and check query works or not . echo "SELECT resorts.resort_name , room_prices.2A FROM resorts inner join room_prices on room_prices.resort_id =resorts.id inner join resort_activities on resorts.id = resort_activities.resort_id inner join activities on resort_activities.id = activities.id WHERE resorts.state_id = (SELECT id FROM states WHERE name = $sname) and activities.activity_name = $activity and room_prices.2A between $min_budget and $max_budget order by room_prices.2A";

Comment: The query is running for all values entered in the database. I tested that before putting the query here @JYoThI

Comment: i think you tested like putting values manually . did you tried like echo the query and copy paste into database and try it . @DhruvVerma

Comment: I tried it manually, I'll try what you told me. I just have to Echo("query") right?

Comment: yes just echo the query . variable will be fill the values . so you can easily find that all variable is correct or not @DhruvVerma

Comment: Where can I see whether it worked or not though? I'm really sorry if my question is very stupid I'm new to php. @JYoThI

Comment: My query is not echoing with the parameters as the values. @JYoThI

Comment: Can you please post your query by printing it?

Comment: Update, I posted another question which describes my problem in a better way. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247754/send-data-to-php-from-android) Please do help me there if you can! @vishalk

Comment: Update, I posted another question which describes my problem in a better way. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247754/send-data-to-php-from-android) Please do help me there if you can! @JYoThI

Answer (score 0):

```
$states = $_GET['states'];
$min_budget = $_GET['min_budget'];
$max_budget = $_GET['max_budget'];
$activity = $_GET['activity'];
```

**Try to access a parameter through $_POST instead of $_GET.**

```
$states = $_POST['states'];
$min_budget = $_POST['min_budget'];
$max_budget = $_POST['max_budget'];
$activity = $_POST['activity'];
```