# Send data to php from Android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm trying to pass parameters to my php script. The data gets passed but always returns "success" as 0. I tested the php by echoing the query after passing values, it works fine and puts all the data. Even var_dump($_POST) indicates it receives data but it always returns "success" as 0. Adding parameters:

```
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("states", states));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("min_budget", min_budget));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("max_budget", max_budget));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("activity", activity));
        Log.d("Passing parameters: ", params.toString());


        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        try {
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_resorts, "POST", params);
```

makeHttpRequest method:`

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
            Log.d("Passing parameters 2: ", params.toString());

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            Log.d("Entity 2: ", httpEntity.toString());
            is = httpEntity.getContent();`
```

logcat

```
Log.d("Passing parameters 2: ", params.toString());
Passing parameters 2:: [states=Himachal Pradesh, min_budget=1,000, max_budget=9,000, activity=Leopard Safari]
```

logcat recieved:

```
  Data received:: array(4) {
            ["states"]=>
            string(16) "Himachal Pradesh"
            ["min_budget"]=>
            string(5) "1,000"
            ["max_budget"]=>
            string(5) "9,000"
            ["activity"]=>
            string(14) "Leopard Safari"
          }

          {"success":0,"message":"No resort found"}
```

Comment: Can you please post your whole php code as well?

Comment: I made it work it was a silly error where I was sending data in a different way than stored in the DB. Thank you for the help though! :) @vishalk